# How to return 206 Response with Streamingout

Tags: java, spring, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I have a jax-rs service implemented in jersey to fetch some millions of record from db

```
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public Response streamExample() {
  StreamingOutput stream = new StreamingOutput() {
    @Override
    public void write(OutputStream os) throws IOException,
    WebApplicationException {
      Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));
     // fetch from resultset and write// writer.write("test");
      writer.flush();  // <-- This is very important.  Do not forget.
    }
  };
  return Response.ok(stream).build();
}
```

I have a test case where i need to respond with HttpStatus :206(partial content), which means there has to be a body with all the results processed and a http status code 206.

All i can implement either client gets a 200(OK), 500(server error), but i have no solution to send the body alongwith a different status code . The reason is first it sets the response status and then calls streaming function(where i call db to fetch all results) lazily. so unless i process the function , i cant say if there will be a 206 error.

How do i implement this?

Comment: `Response.status(206).entity(stream).build();`

Comment: that will return 206 for all the request, i have a specific scenario to respond with 206 not for all

Comment: Are you saying you want to read the stream first to test whether is to should be a 200 or not? Not sure what you're asking.

Comment: i flush the stream while i read data from db. which means ii can send very large data. Now if i start reading this large volume,  it may give OutOfMemory.

Comment: Thus after i am proessed streaming all data  ,at the end i want to somehow let the client know that we couldnt process all data and send a 206 code

Comment: Still not sure what you're asking. You're saying something about tryin to set the status after the stream has started reading. This is not possible. The status code is part of the response header as specified by HTTP, so this header is already written to the response stream back to client even before the entity stream starts reading.

Comment: i feel this isnt possible, because a 200 is set at first , then stream the data, and at the end i cant send/change another status code

Comment: can i set something in header

Comment: With curl, do `curl -i google.com`. The first line of the response is the status line. This is written back to the client before any processing of the entity.

Comment: You can't add anything to the header either, for the same reason. Everything is processed back to the client as a stream of data, from status line to response headers, to entity body; in that order.

Comment: it seems only response code possible is 200 or 500. was seeing if anyone had done any work around.

Comment: Maybe use pagination to avoid allowing large responses like this, or use [Chunked Output](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/async.html#chunked-output)

Comment: In short, pagination is not the solution, To describe i have to write the whole big story. :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177135/discussion-between-surya-and-paul-samsotha).